# How can I smoothly transition between hardware cameras?

Tags: flutter, dart

- I'm using the [`camera`](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package.
- I'm looking for a way to smoothly transition between the ultra-wide and wide camera lenses.
- The transition from ultra wide to wide should occur when the camera's zoom is `>= 1.0`.

My main issue is that I can't make the transition between the ultra wide and wide lens happen smoothly. I have to `dispose` the old `CameraController`, to then `initialize` the new one. This creates a noticeable jump when switching cameras.

A smooth transition can be seen on the iPhone 14's camera application. Zoom in slowly from .5 to 1.0 and you will see the camera transition occur through a fade/opacity transition. I want to replicate that.